# Upload iPhone HD videos to YouTube

Tags: video, youtube

Modern iPhones capture full hi-def videos with 1920x1080 resolution. When I download the MOV file to my computer and then upload it to YouTube, it only shows as 360p resolution.
**How do you upload iPhone videos to YouTube keeping their HD resolution?**

Comment: what uploader app are you using ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 - Native YouTube web uploader from a MOV file on my system downloaded from the iPhone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm... turns out YouTube shows HD options for the video only some time after the video is uploaded. My guess would be that YouTube continues processing the video in the background and exposes the various resolutions only when they are done processing.

So the answer is: just upload your HD videos, it'll retain the resolution after a while